# PL/SQL Procedure Amendment

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

Currently we have an issue with a procedure. An amendment to the procedure to differentiate the returned value determined on if the Machine Type is 'ROAD TRAILER' or 'ROAD WAGON'.

The view which has these values and know that we can use '**MCH_CODE**' to create a relationship between ACTIVE_WORK_ORDER_TAB and EQUIPMENT_FUNCTIONAL_UIV.

Tables I think are required (some currently in use)

- **EQUIPMENT_FUNCTIONAL_UIV** (required for MCH_TYPE and joins on VIA MCH_CODE to ACTIVE_WORK_ORDER_TAB
- **ACTIVE_WORK_ORDER_TAB**

Basically, this is how it should read however, I'm finding it difficult to update the procedure every time I've amended the statement it has broken.

If the MCH_TYPE is ROAD_WAGON or ROAD_TRAILER and TEMP_ in ('682','720','770','775','784') then return 14

ELSEIF the MCH_TYPE is NOT 'ROAD_WAGON' or 'ROAD_TRAILER' and TEMP_ in ('720') then return 14

Example of procedure below:

```
temp_               NUMBER;
  serv_               VARCHAR2(100);
  attr_               VARCHAR2(2000);
  info_               VARCHAR2(2000);
  WO_STATUS_ID_       VARCHAR2(200);
  Record_Found_       BOOLEAN;
  contract_           VARCHAR2(200);
  Pre_Accounting_id_  NUMBER;
  LoopCount_          NUMBER;

  CURSOR get_preacc IS
     SELECT * 
     FROM PRE_ACCOUNTING
     WHERE pre_accounting_id = Pre_Accounting_id_ ;

  CURSOR get_rec IS  
     SELECT WO_STATUS_ID,contract
     FROM ACTIVE_WORK_ORDER_TAB
     WHERE PRE_ACCOUNTING_ID = Pre_Accounting_id_;


BEGIN
  Pre_Accounting_Id_ := Client_sys.Get_Item_Value('PRE_ACCOUNTING_ID', Pre_Accounting_Attr_);
  Record_Found_      := FALSE;
  FOR c_get_rec IN get_rec LOOP
     Record_Found_ := TRUE;
     WO_STATUS_ID_ := c_get_rec.wo_status_id;
     contract_     := c_get_rec.contract;
  END LOOP;
  IF NVL(WO_STATUS_ID_,'XXX1') NOT IN ('RELEASED','STARTED','FAULTREPORT', 'WORKREQUEST') THEN
     RETURN;
  END IF;
  LoopCount_ := 0;
  <<IF_ERROR_LOOP>>
  BEGIN
      FOR x_ IN get_preacc LOOP
         BEGIN
          temp_ := to_number(x_.codeno_b);
         EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS then
            temp_ := 0;
         END;
         IF temp_ >= 450 and temp_ <= 470 THEN
            serv_ := '12';
         ELSIF temp_ = 682 or temp_ = 720 or temp_ = 770 or temp_ = 775 or temp_ = 784 THEN
            serv_ := '14';
         ELSIF temp_ = 950 THEN
            serv_ := '12';
         ELSIF temp_ = 685 THEN
            serv_ := '22';
         ELSE
            serv_ := '16';
         END IF;

         IF nvl(x_.CODENO_C,'X') = serv_ THEN
             RETURN;
         END IF;
         Client_SYS.clear_Attr(attr_);
         Client_SYS.Add_To_Attr('CODENO_C', serv_,attr_); 
         Client_SYS.Add_To_Attr('COMPANY', Site_API.Get_Company(contract_),attr_); 
         Client_SYS.Add_To_Attr('CONTRACT', contract_,attr_); 

         PRE_ACCOUNTING_API.Modify__(info_,x_.objid,x_.objversion,attr_,'DO');
      END LOOP;
   EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            LoopCount_ := LoopCount_ +1;
            IF LoopCount_ < 20 THEN
                DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP (20);
                GOTO IF_ERROR_LOOP;
            END IF;
   END;
```

Comment: It's a little unclear exactly what the question is. What needs to be fixed?

Comment: If you’re trying to use `ELSEIF` as mentioned in your question, it should be `ELSIF`. Otherwise, some more details about what exactly is "broken" would help.

Comment: @TadHarrison We've recently amended the application the procedure runs. With this amendment the condition doesn't work as the temp_ column returns 720 which can either mean 14 OR 20. To fix this I've found if we include an additional condition
of MCH_TYPE it can distinguish which value should be returned. 
If temp_ = '720' and MCH_TYPE is ROAD_TRAILER or ROAD_WAGON then return 20
 ELSIF temp_ = '720' and MCH_TYPE is not ROAD_TRAILER or ROAD_WAGON then return 14
 Problem is I don't write procedures and I'm struggling to include the view EQUIPMENT_FUNCTIONAL_UIV and then amend the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the problem by simply including the following in to the stored procedure:

```
 BEGIN
  FOR x_ IN get_preacc LOOP


     BEGIN
      temp_ := to_number(x_.codeno_b);
      MCH_TYPE := MCH_TYPE;
     EXCEPTION

     WHEN OTHERS then
        temp_ := 0;
     END;

     IF temp_ >= 450 
       and temp_ <= 470 THEN
        serv_ := '12';

         ELSIF (temp_ = 720 and (MCH_TYPE = 'ROAD WAGON' OR  MCH_TYPE = 'ROAD TRAILER'))
         then serv_ := '20';  

         ELSIF temp_ = 682
         or (temp_ = 720 and (MCH_TYPE != 'ROAD WAGON' OR  MCH_TYPE != 'ROAD TRAILER'))
         or temp_ = 770 
         or temp_ = 775 
         or temp_ = 784 
         THEN
         serv_ := '14';

     ELSIF temp_ = 950 THEN
        serv_ := '12';

     ELSIF temp_ = 741 
       or temp_ = 773 
       or temp_ = 774 
       or temp_ = 775 
       or temp_ = 740 THEN
       serv_ := '22';


     ELSIF temp_ = 685 THEN
        serv_ := '22';

     ELSE
        serv_ := '16';
     END IF;

     IF nvl(x_.CODENO_C,'X') = serv_ THEN
         RETURN;
     END IF;
     Client_SYS.clear_Attr(attr_);
     Client_SYS.Add_To_Attr('CODENO_C', serv_,attr_); 
     Client_SYS.Add_To_Attr('COMPANY', Site_API.Get_Company(contract_),attr_); 
     Client_SYS.Add_To_Attr('CONTRACT', contract_,attr_); 
     PRE_ACCOUNTING_API.Modify__(info_,x_.objid,x_.objversion,attr_,'DO');
  END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 0):

paperclipsandpaper, Like Tad I am not sure what your issue is but if you are trying to add another condition when the temp_ is 720 then maybe the following will help you figure out your problem.

```
elsif temp_ in (682,770,775,784) then serv_ := 14;
elsif temp_ = 720 and mch_type not in ('ROAD_WAGON','ROAD_TRAILER') then serv_ := 14;
elsif temp- = 950 ...
```

Comment: I've included some notes to TADS comment above. Basically additional conditions are required and I'm struggling to include an additional view EQUIPMENT_FUNCTIONAL_UIV to amend the condition. Please see Tad's comment for additional information